# plugin_dir_url & plugin_basename not working when plugin dir is outside wordpress dir

Tags: plugin-development

I have been using these functions for quite a while now but yesterday I noticed that they were not working properly on a site where the plugin directory was outside the main WordPress folder.

`WP_PLUGIN_DIR` and `WP_PLUGIN_URL` have been set properly like so:

```
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/var/www/plugins' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://test.com/plugins' );
```

Now if the value of `__FILE__` is `/var/www/plugins/forms-plugin/forms-plugin.php` and I pass it to `plugin_basename()`, I get this:

```
var/www/plugins/forms-plugin/forms-plugin.php
```

Instead of just the plugin name.

If I pass it to `plugin_dir_url()`, I get:

```
http://test.com/plugins/var/www/plugins/forms-plugin/
```

Instead of the correct value: http://test.com/plugins/forms-plugin/

Everything works properly when the same plugin is placed inside the WP directory and the constants `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` and `WP_PLUGIN_URL` are not used.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. Working perfectly here. Can you provide exact steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: "If I pass it to" - if you pass what?

Comment: @MarkKaplun If I pass the FILE variable which has the value /var/www/plugins/forms-plugin/forms-plugin.php

Comment: @cybmeta All you have to do is move the plugin's directory outside the wordpress directory using the constants WP_PLUGIN_DIR and WP_PLUGIN_URL. Then inside a plugin file use the function plugin_dir_url and pass it the __FILE__ magic constant.

Comment: As I said, I did it and it worked perfectly here. Following those steps doesn't casue the issue you are describing; that is why I asked you the exact steps to reproduce the problem. It seems that you/we are missing something.

Comment: `echo plugin_dir_url ( __FILE__)` should be the same as `echo implode ( WP_PLUGIN_URL, explode (WP_PLUGIN_DIR, __FILE__ ) );`

Comment: @cybmeta It's really weird that you can't reproduce this error on your end. I have tried this multiple times and it always gives the same result. Can I include any more information in the question to help you understand what might be going wrong on my end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was adding a trailing slash to `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` in my `wp-config.php` which was causing this issue. Hopefully this will help someone making the same mistake.

Comment: _"Hopefully this will help someone making the same mistake"_ … hopefully this helps **avoiding** the mistake.

Comment: Please consider accepting your answer so that the question shows as answered.